# Network Watcher ARM Template Fails to Deploy

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Trying to add an extension arm template to our Windows VM deployments, and noticed it is failing to validate the extension template. The Network Watcher Arm template fails to deploy with the below error message. Not sure what I could be missing here. I tried following the schema, found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/network-watcher-windows#extension-schema).

> ERROR TYPE
> Deployment template validation failed: 'The template
> resource 'networkWatcherAgent' for type
> 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions' at line '24' and column
> '64' has incorrect segment lengths. A nested resource type must have
> identical number of segments as its resource name. A root resource
> type must have segment length one greater than its resource name.
> Please see https://aka.ms/arm-syntax-resources for usage details.'.
> (Code: InvalidTemplate)

Arm template:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "vmName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "apiVersion": "2022-11-01"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "networkWatcherAgent",
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
            "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('vmName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.NetworkWatcher",
                "type": "NetworkWatcherAgentWindows",
                "typeHandlerVersion": "1.4"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: changing the "name" to 'Microsoft.Azure.NetworkWatcher' also fails.
ERROR TYPE
Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'Microsoft.Azure.NetworkWatcher' for type 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions' at line '24' and column '64' has incorrect segment lengths. A nested resource type must have identical number of segments as its resource name. A root resource type must have segment length one greater than its resource name. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-syntax-resources for usage details.'. (Code: InvalidTemplate)

Answer (score 1):

> The Network Watcher Arm template fails to deploy with the below error message.

There might be a misunderstanding in the template structure; the dependency on `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines` might be causing issue.

[image]

Here is the updated `ARM` template to create a `Network Watcher Agent` extension in an existing `Windows VM`.

```json
    {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "parameters": {
            "vmName": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "variables": {
            "apiVersion": "2022-11-01"
        },
        "resources": [
            {
                "name": "[parameters('vmName')]",
                "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
                "apiVersion": "2022-11-01",
                "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                "properties": {
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), '/networkWatcherAgent')]",
                "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
                "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
                "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('vmName'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                    "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.NetworkWatcher",
                    "type": "NetworkWatcherAgentWindows",
                    "typeHandlerVersion": "1.4"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: that worked! thank you! not sure why that dependency for the vm resource is neded there, you dont need it for other vm extensions.  If you look at the json object of the VM itself the type is under Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions rather than Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<vmName>/networkWatcherAgent

Comment: The dependency on the VM resource is needed to ensure that the **Network Watcher Agent** extension is deployed only after the virtual machine is successfully provisioned. While other VM extensions may not explicitly include this dependency, it is a best practice to ensure proper sequencing and avoid potential deployment issues related to dependencies.